# Multi dimension flavor - shared resources

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavors

**SOLVED

Solution was a 'prod2' source set. Even if it wasn't working before, probably a clean build was the solution.**

I have a 2-dimensional flavored android-project.

It it flavored like this:

```
flavorDimensions "product", "brand"

productFlavors {
    prod1 {
        flavorDimension "product"
    }

    prod2 {
        flavorDimension "product"
    }

    brand1 {
        flavorDimension "brand"
    }

    brand2 {
        flavorDimension "brand"
    }
}
```

The problem:
They all have shared code in 'main' that uses resources from the different products.
Prod2 has some shared resources for both brands.
How can I create shared resources only for prod2Brand1 and prod2Brand2?

I already tried to put the resources in a folder named 'prod2' and 'prod2Main'.

Comment: What was the problem with a `prod2` source set?

Comment: The problem was, that no resources out of this source set could be found while building.
Anyway, I tried it again today and now its working.. Probably a clean or something was the solution.